# Running a t-sql stored procedure with EXECUTE AS statement with .NET SqlCommand

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, sspi

I have a .NET web service application that executes parameterized MS SQL Server stored procedures using System.Data.SqlCommand. The application receives a name of the stored procedure and its parameters from user input.

Also the application deployed within Windows AD domain and it is able to obtain the name of a remote user with the help of SSPI authentication.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
  using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(procedureName, con)) {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    foreach (var pair in pairs.AllKeys) {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(pair, pairs[pair]));
    }
    con.Open();
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
      // processing results
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to execute a stored procedure with an EXECUTE AS statement.

```
use [db]
go
execute as user = 'domain\user' --execute as RemoteUser
exec [db].[stored_procdure] @param1=value1
```

Can this be done? How can I add EXECUTE AS to the SqlCommand?

I would not like to resort to sql injection prone code and build the sql request from strings received from user.

Comment: why don't you specify the username in the connection string when you create the sql connection object, you will execute it as that user this way

Comment: Use ``Windows Authentication`` to connect to SQL Server and not the ``sa`` user.

Comment: I cannot specify the user credentials in the connection string as I don't have them. I have only a user name in 'domain\user' format. No password.

Comment: @rand-random I already use Windows Authentication.

Comment: if  you use windows authentication then why do you need to execute as user ?

Comment: Than why would you need "execute as" your commands are already executing as the user that uses the connection?!?

Comment: Tell us what your stored procedure does or you want it to do, maybe there is a different solution you didnt think of.

Comment: I use windows domain service account to access the database, then I want to execute stored procedures with the remote user account. Thus implementing the RBAC stepping aside the double-hop authentication problem.

Comment: The stored procedures do manipulate data. Users should access  only those that they are allowed to.

Comment: You might want to set up a Kerberos delegation, here is some discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077046/impersonation-and-delegation-with-sql-server-in-asp-net . Be mindful, however, that it's trickier than it looks, so first secure the help of a system engineer experienced with AD.

Comment: @RogerWolf Sadly, that's not an option, because I'm working in a large company and the Kerberos token for some users can be bloated above the MaxTokenSize. And remediation will take a lot more than you'd think https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/327825.

Comment: Seems like you need two connections to the database, each with different credentials. Might be simpler to use windows authentication for the user connection and SQL Server service account instead a domain service account for the other?

Comment: @Mic No. I need exactly one connection per user request. And I want to use Windows Authentication with SQL Server always. And I have it already. The thing I need is to implement EXECUTE AS while doing the parameterized stored procedure call.

Comment: @prot, you actually ran into the MaxTokenSize limit? Is there still Windows 2000 in your network, unpatched? In any case, what you want is impossible, because if anyone could create an arbitrary Kerberos token only from their login, it wouldn't be called "security".

Comment: @RogerWolf, yes for the limit and no for win2k. I work in a huge corporation with rather complicated security group model. 
I don't want to re-create a Kerberos token, I want to re-create an application-level trust rather than a server-level. I do trust the application, as I am the developer, and I do trust it to access the database with the credentials (an ID actually) that it gets from IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it some time ago with a colleague of mine.

To achieve the requested behavior the `execute as` statement should be run in a separate preceeding SqlCommand while in the same SqlConnection.

After the closing of the `reader`, still in the same SqlConnection, there's another separate SqlCommand needed - `revert` - to switch back the context.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue where I was able to Execute as User but the Revert wasn't working. By following prot's answer I was able to fix it. So for anyone having a similar issue this is how the code looks

```
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EXECUTE AS USER = 'domain\\user';");
   OSSDBDataContext dc = new OSSDBDataContext();
   cmd.Connection = dc.Connection as SqlConnection;
   cmd.Connection.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

   //Execute stored procedure code goes here

   SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("REVERT;");
   cmd2.Connection = dc.Connection as SqlConnection;
   cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```